# how to turn lock aspect ratio on/off programatically

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, vuedraggable

[codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/little-snow-jzoz3?file=/src/components/Test.vue)

As you can see in the sandbox, lock-aspect-ratio property works as expected. However, I'd like to change width/height programmatically with a different aspect ratio from the original one and then make lock-aspect-ratio active again. Any possible ways to do this? I wanna stick with the same lock-aspect-ratio when it comes to resizing.

```
setSize: function () {
  # something like this.$refs.vueDraggableResizeable.lockAspectRatio = false
  this.w = 300;
  this.h = 100;
  # something like this.$refs.vueDraggableResizeable.lockAspectRatio = true 
}
```

Comment: Did this comment help at all? 

https://github.com/mauricius/vue-draggable-resizable/issues/116

Comment: thought setting variable ```:lock-aspect-ratio="lock"``` works, but it doesn't. if I set ```this.lock = true``` again after ```this.h = 100```, it constraints the aspect ratio with initial aspect ratio.

Comment: Sorry, I don't see any problem. Did you solve it or can you explain more on it.